# How to counter conflicting types error when dealing with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

new to coding and I'm learning by doing questions.In this question were im stuck at im supposed to write code which takes input in array and prints it using pointers.Here is the code below please point out where i got it wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* record_array (int *size_ptr);
void print_array (int *array_ptr , int *size_ptr);


int* record_array (int *size_ptr)
{
    int *array_ptr = (int*) malloc(*size_ptr * sizeof(int));
    for (int index = 0;index < *size_ptr;++index)
    {
        printf("Enter element at index %d : ", index);
        scanf("%d", &array_ptr[index]);
    }
    return array_ptr;
}
void print_array (int *array_ptr, int *size_ptr)
{
    for (int index = 0;index < *size_ptr;++index)
    {
        printf("%d ",array_ptr[index]);
    }

}

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int *array = NULL;

    printf("How many elements do you want?");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    array = record_array(&size);
    print_array(array,&size);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: Since you don't update `size` in the functions, why are you passing it by reference? Just pass `size` instead of `&size`

Comment: why are you giving size by ref ?

Answer (score 0):

When you test some ideas do not `scanf` values. `scanf` can be quite tricky for the beginners. Use also the correct types.

You do not need to pass the size of the array by the reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* record_array (size_t size);
void print_array (const int *array_ptr, size_t size);

int* record_array (size_t size)
{
    int *array_ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(*array_ptr));
    for (size_t index = 0;index < size; ++index)
    {
        array_ptr[index] = index;
    }
    return array_ptr;
}
void print_array (const int *array_ptr, size_t size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s", array_ptr[index], (index % 6) ? "" : "\n");
    }

}

int main()
{
    size_t size = 0;
    int *array = NULL;

    printf("How many elements do you want?");
    scanf("%zu", &size);
    array = record_array(size);
    print_array(array,size);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/J9SEne

If you want to use pointers to pass the size (and you do not change it in the functions)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* record_array (const size_t *size);
void print_array (const int *array_ptr, const size_t *size);


int* record_array (const size_t *size)
{
    int *array_ptr = malloc(*size * sizeof(*array_ptr));
    for (size_t index = 0;index < *size; ++index)
    {
        array_ptr[index] = index;
    }
    return array_ptr;
}
void print_array (const int *array_ptr, const size_t *size)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < *size; ++index)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s", array_ptr[index], (index % 6) ? "" : "\n");
    }

}

int main()
{
    size_t size = 0;
    int *array = NULL;

    printf("How many elements do you want?");
    scanf("%zu", &size);
    array = record_array(&size);
    print_array(array,&size);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Vwt9oS

Remember that you always check the passed pointers if they are not `NULL` and check the result of the `malloc`